# Intermittent Slow MongoDB Queries in Dockerized FastAPI App

Tags: mongodb, docker, pymongo, fastapi

I'm developing a FastAPI app locally on my laptop using Docker, and I'm encountering a crazy issue where some MongoDB queries experience random latency spikes.

**Issue Description**:

My MongoDB queries, at times, take an unusually long time (upwards of 5 seconds) to execute. This behavior occurs sporadically; the same query might execute normally in 0.003 seconds on one occasion and take 5 seconds on another, with no clear pattern.

**Example:**

The issue arises even with simple queries, like the following (note that `db` is of type `pymongo.database.Database`):

```
db["users"].find_one({"name": name})
```

In this case, the "users" collection literally only has 1 record but can still take extremely long (5+ seconds) at random (maybe ~30% of the time).

**Explain output**

The output of `.explain()["executionStats"]` on a slow query (the same query as above) suggests that the MongoDB itself is only taking 1ms to complete, and yet the overall Python call takes over 5 seconds.

```
{'executionSuccess': True, 'nReturned': 1, 'executionTimeMillis': 1, 'totalKeysExamined': 0, 'totalDocsExamined': 1, 'executionStages': {'stage': 'limit', 'planNodeId': 2, 'nReturned': 1, 'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 0, 'opens': 1, 'closes': 1, 'saveState': 0, 'restoreState': 0, 'isEOF': 1, 'limit': 1, 'inputStage': {'stage': 'filter', 'planNodeId': 1, 'nReturned': 1, 'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 0, 'opens': 1, 'closes': 1, 'saveState': 0, 'restoreState': 0, 'isEOF': 0, 'numTested': 1, 'filter': 'traverseF(s4, lambda(l1.0) { ((l1.0 == s7) ?: false) }, false) ', 'inputStage': {'stage': 'scan', 'planNodeId': 1, 'nReturned': 1, 'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 0, 'opens': 1, 'closes': 1, 'saveState': 0, 'restoreState': 0, 'isEOF': 0, 'numReads': 1, 'recordSlot': 5, 'recordIdSlot': 6, 'fields': ['name'], 'outputSlots': [4]}}}, 'allPlansExecution': []}
```

**Other observations**

- I've confirmed via docker stats that the containers are not resource-constrained.
- CPU usage can spike a little during (or more often immediately after) the query, up to around 40%, but only briefly and not consistently associated with the slowdown.
- The application is containerized with Docker; one container runs the FastAPI backend, and another runs MongoDB
- I haven't been able to replicate the issue in a standalone script, running the queries in isolation never creates a slowdown

I'm at my wits end, and talking with GPT4 hasn't produced any leads. Would really appreciate any advice anyone might have!!

Comment: Maybe you can test the mongodb query separately via sql in mongodb shell.If there is no problem with sql but there is a problem with fastapi, you can check the python level problem in detail.

Comment: Could there be a communications stall between containers?  If you communicate between containers, independently of MongoDB (e.g., ftp, ssh, ...), do you see "pauses"?

Comment: Thank you, running the db query separately in isolation never produces the slowdown.

Hmmm good idea... I ran ping from the backend container to mongo (and visa versa) while using my frontend to reproduce the latency spike, and the slowdown didn't reflect in the ping messages :(

Comment: Following up for whoever reads this thread, I am guessing it may be related to slow Docker performance on Mac: https://www.atatus.com/blog/fixing-dockers-slow-performance-on-macos/

and gave up